# iPhone randomly reboots into safe mode when opening apps

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, crash, safe-mode

Today when I opened my Beststream app, my iPhone boots into Safe Mode. This has happend to me alot this year. I don't like this as all because sometimes, I restart into safe mode, and other times, I do normal safe mode. It just happens sometimes. I've been thinking alot about that it is the RAM that's being overloaded, but I don't know. I have alot of junk from other tweaks that I've removed. Anyways, the crash report can be found here: http://pastebin.com/AAn4AZVa

Specs:

iPhone 4 8GB

Comment: Did you jailbreak your phone? And what exactly do you mean with "safe mode"?

Answer (score 2):

*If you mean [MobileSubstrate SafeMode](http://cydia.saurik.com/safemode/)…*

Since it has happened multiple times, restarting hasn't seemed to fix it. Consequently, I would recommend performing the following:

1. Remove recently installed extensions.

   If you know that you recently installed a Cydia package, or updated one, I would suggest uninstalling that package and see if it makes a difference.
2. Use [Crash Reporter](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/crash-reporter).

   Crash Reporter will attempt to guess the cause of a crash. After installing, next time your iPhone crashes, you can check the 'Possible Causes' list in Crash Reporter for its guess on the cause. You can then try to delete the package in Cydia and see if that fixes the problem.